# Writing to a csv file using C causing problems

Tags: c, database, file, csv, struct

I was writing to a CSV file using a C program and something weird is happening.

- If I leave the cursor at a new line at the last(when I  open it with a text editor), it leaves a line and then writes. For that, I tried it to get back to the start using rewind and then SEEK_END(with offset as 0 and then  -1) but it doesn't seem 
  to work.
- If the cursor is set to the last of the last line, it just works fine.

here is the code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "Project.h"

void WriteEmployeeData(employee empF){
    FILE *f;;
    f=fopen("employee.csv","a");
        // printf("%ld\n",ftell(f));
        printf("%d\n",fseek(f, 0, SEEK_END));
        // printf("%ld\n",ftell(f));
        fprintf(f,"%d,%s,%ld,%s,%d\n",empF.employee_id,empF.employee_name,empF.phno,empF.shift,empF.area_code);

    fclose(f);


}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{   employee e[100];
    int len=0;
    ReadEmployeeData(e,&len);
    WriteEmployeeData(e[2]);
    // WriteEmployeeData(e[3]);


    /* code */
    return 0;
}
```

this is the output for the conditions of the first case(when the cursor is set to the last of the file in a new line)

```
Employee_ID,Employee_Name,Phone_number,Shift,Area_Code^M
10111,John Smith,9933432921,9:00-13:00,201301^M
10112,Robert ,3914323431,10:00-13:00,201304^M
10113,Will,8884923312,16:00-20:00,110006^M
10114,Rakesh,9090991023,12:00-16:00,110076^M
10115,Kumaar,8292231231,8:00-12:00,201103^M
10116,Arbind,7318341312,11:00-13:00,120331^M
10117,Saurabh,8887567456,12:00-17:30,110087^M
10118,Ram Kumar,1230232331,10:30-18:00,110011^M
10119,Shiv,3213233123,11:30-15:30,201893^M
10120,Lakshay,4355634545,13:00-19:00,121232^M
10121,Rohan,9990999701,11:45-15:00,8773911^M
10113,Will,8884923312,16:00-20:00,110006^M
10114,Rakesh,9090991023,12:00-16:00,110076^M
^M
10113,Will,8884923312,16:00-20:00,110006
```

how can I prevent the addition of that extra line
when I opened this csv in vim, this is what I got.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the CSV file you try to write into, has `\r\n` (which stand for resp. carriage return <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>M</kbd> and new line or line feed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>J</kbd>) at the end of each line. It is probably a file coming from a MS operating system. You see it when you open the file with `vim`: the text editor displays `^M` for showing that some lines are terminated only with `\n` (the last line you added) and others with `\r\n`. Why the letter M? Because `\r` (carriage return) is the same as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>M</kbd>.

You try to write into this file with another logic, with only `\n` as ine separator. This would work if you convert first your "carriage return + line feed" CSV file into a "line feed" only CSV file, with an utility like `dos2unix`.

If you need to keep the CSV file as it is, remind to finish each line you write with `\r\n` instead of `\n`, and if you want to overwrite a blank line at the end of the file, seek back with 2 positions to overwrite both `\n` and `\r`.

Comment: I tried what u told me to, I tried writing files using '\r\n' but the issue still persists. If I keep the cursor on a new line before saving, it makes a blank line, and if the cursor is at the last of the last line, no blank line appears then.